# Error running expo android app in production mode - React-native

Tags: javascript, android, react-native, expo

Pretty new to expo so not sure what this error means am getting this when I run expo in production mode

[image]

After I try reloading the app it gets stuck at the new update downloading

[image]

Would be highly appreciated if anyone can help! Let me know if any more details needed.

Answer (score 0):

Are you running the app in expo go (mobile) or Android emulator ?

If expo go, then connect to tunnel from metro bundle and then scan it again

Comment: I am running it as an apk on my phone